# How to access a specific view in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone viev which generates a list item view.  In the render function it goes through the collection and generates each of the sub item views with some standard code as follows:

```
render: function () {
    _(this.collection.models).each(function(item){
        $this.appendItem(item);
     }, this);          
},
```

I would like to know how to access a specific view from the item list, say at position 0 or something.  I want to be able to trigger a function from the item list view for that specific item.

Comment: Pls explain what you want to achieve, ther may be a better solution if we know wait you aim for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that depends on how the `appendItem` function is implemented, I guess is in there where you build the *SubViews*.

You can store each created SubView in an Array so the Array will offer you a way to manipulate the SubViews.

But if I can offer a piece of advice I would say that this is a *code smell* from the begining. Instead of trying to manipulate a concrete SubView you can manipulate the Model which is associated with the SubView and make the SubView to be listening to this change.

Then you will start to be thinking in manipulating Models instead of Views.

Comment: For now I just want to set the first item in the collection to active, however I need to update a bunch of other elements on the page like dropdowns and text fields with values from the particular model from that collection.  So it's not an update, more like a 'toggle' event.  I normally call this toggle from the view when I click on a menu item, which will then update all those elements.  However I just need to initialize it with something on load.  For now it would just be the first item, however later I would also like to be able to set a specific model from the collection.

Comment: @Rob you can _trigger_ custom events on the Model and listen them from the View as normal _change_ events.

Comment: Okay, I was making this out to be much more complicated then it had to be, I definitely had something's laid out incorrectly in my backbone app.  Short answer though, I just pass the "active" id to the appendItem call then just have this after the `.append()` call:  `if(item.id == active_id)matterItem.$el.trigger('click');`